# Gluing a variadic template to a variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, variadic-templates

In an attempt to bypass GCC's unimplemented always-inlining variadic functions in libc++, I thought I could maybe wrap the variadic functions (like snprintf, more precisely, the *_l variant) in a variadic template to achieve a similar effect. An instantiation would fill in the variadic function's varargs, allowing the function to be nicely inlined. The problem is, I don't know the first thing about writing variadic templates, and I certainly don't know how to turn the template arguments into seperate arguments.

The code I'm looking to replace is of the form:

```
int __sprintf_l(char *__s, locale_t __l, const char *__format, ...) {
  va_list __va;
  va_start(__va, __format);
  int __res = vsprintf_l(__s, __l, __format, __va);
  va_end(__va);
  return __res;
}
```

I'd like to replace is with something of the form:

```
template<typename... Args>
int __sprintf_l(char *__s, locale_t __l, const char *__format, Args... args) {
  int __res = vsprintf_l(__s, __l, __format, args...);
  return __res;
}
```

This is not working, due to the expanded `args...` which cannot be converted to `type` to `va_list {aka char*}`. If there is no way, I'll have to trust Howard and implement one-, and two-argument always-inline templates, which would effectively double the amount of needed code.

EDIT: perhaps a way to convert the `std::tuple` that `args` is into a va_list would work here?

Comment: Isn't the implementation of a `va_list` implementation defined? So there is at least no portable way to convert it, right? Also, `boost::format` could be an alternative.

Comment: Just to be clear, `args` is not at all an `std::tuple`.  It is its own unique entity, with a name I forget off hand.  `args...` essentially expands out to `arg0, arg1, arg2, ..., argN`; in other words, if `vsprintf_l` accepted a variable number of arguments, rather than a single `va_list` object, what you did would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question you're asking is confusing so let me restate it.

You want to use variadic templates to write a function that simulates inlining a variadic function.

It cannot be done.  `va_args` is often implemented as a void* to the first parameter on the stack (note variadic functions are required to have at least one non-variadic argument for exactly this reason).

You would need to manipulate the call stack to get the parameters in the right place.  Now it might be the case that the variadic template function's arguments are on the stack in the same location as `va_args` would want them but that would require the template function to not be inlined.

I strongly suspect the reason always inlining variadic function is unimplemented is because of the implementation of va_args assume standard stack layout.  For the compiler to inline that function it would need to allocate stack space and copy the parameters in place.  The only thing it would save is actual `jmp` and `ret` instructions.

It could be done, but half of the benefits of inlining evaporate.  Further the compiler will have to hoist the parameter passing code (compiler code that is) to a more general location for use with regular function calls as forced inline of variadic functions.  In other words it complicates the control flow significantly for small to no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own sprintf_l

```
int __noninlined_sprintf_l(char *__s, locale_t __l, const char *__format, ...) {
  va_list __va;
  va_start(__va, __format);
  int __res = vsprintf_l(__s, __l, __format, __va);
  va_end(__va);
  return __res;
}
```

And call that instead

```
template<typename... Args>
int __sprintf_l(char *__s, locale_t __l, const char *__format, Args... args) {
  int __res = __noninlined_sprintf_l(__s, __l, __format, args...);
  return __res;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but due to what deft_code says above, didn't work completely... The code was removed for my use-case, so the problematic code became unused, solving the direct problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename... T>
int
variadic(char* s, locale_t locale, const char* format, T&&... t)
{
    return __sprintf_l(s, locale, format, std::forward<T>(t)...);
}
```

Then calling `variadic(s, l, "%d %s", 42, "Hello")` would result in a call to `__sprintf_l(s, l, "%d %s", 42, "Hello")`.

Comment: Although I like the code, this is not what the question asked.  I'm not going to -1 though as the question is poorly worded.